# MetalLB External IP to Internet

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, bare-metal-server, metallb

I can't access to public IP assigned by MetalLB load Balancer

I created a Kubernetes cluster in Contabo. Its 1 master and 2 workers. Each one has its own public IP.

I did it with kubeadm + flannel. Later I did install MetalLB to use Load Balancing.

I used this manifest for installing nginx:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
```

It works, pods are running. I see the external IP adress after:

```
kubectl get services
```

[image]
From each node/host I can curl to that ip and port and I can get nginx's:

```
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
```

So far, so good. BUT:

What I still miss is to access to that service (nginx) from my computer. 
I can try to access to each node (master + 2 slaves) by their IP:PORT and nothing happens. The final goal is to have a domain that access to that service but I can't guess witch IP should I use.

What I'm missing?

Should MetalLB just expose my 3 possible IPs?
Should I add something else on each server as a reverse proxy?

I'm asking this here because all articles/tutorials on baremetal/VPS (non aws,GKE, etc...) do this on a kube on localhost and miss this basic issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm kind of doing the same thing than you, but I haven't install MetalLB as it requires a free range of IP addresses, which I haven't (as you said, Contabo don't have that). You've accepted the answer from Bouzid Amine, can you please tell what you did in order to get the LoadBalancer service having the `EXTERNAL-IP` being the public IP addresses of the nodes?

Comment: I am also searching for a solution for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are missing is a routing policy

Your external IP addresses must belong to the same network as your nodes or instead of that  you can add a route to your external address at your default gateway level and use a static NAT for each address

Comment: Theres no internal network in Contabo, I had to use public IP when I created the cluster:  NAME                          STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP      EXTERNAL-IP 
vmi239001.contaboserver.net   Ready    master   14h   v1.15.1   213.00.92.165   <none>       
vmi241004.contaboserver.net   Ready    <none>   14h   v1.15.1   173.000.35.231   <none>      
vmi278000.contaboserver.net   Ready    <none>   14h   v1.15.1   80.000.219.21    <none>

Comment: So, I should  route to your external address at your default gateway level ?

Comment: can anyone give an example on this, `Your external IP addresses must belong to the same network as your nodes` what does it mean? How can I implement this

Comment: @Amine Bouzid, any help, ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I am having the very same hardware layout:

- a 3-Nodes Kubernetes Cluster - here with the 3 IPs:
  | 123.223.149.27
  | 22.36.211.68
  | 192.77.11.164 |
- running on (different) VPS-Providers (connected to a running cluster(via JOIN), of course)

**Target: "expose" the nginx via metalLB, so I can access my web-app from outside the cluster via browser via the IP of one of my VPS'**

**Problem: I do not have *a "range of IPs"* I could declare for the metallb**

Steps done:

1. create one .yaml file for the Loadbalancer, the **kindservicetypeloadbalancer.yaml**
2. create one .yaml file for the ConfigMap, containing the IPs of the 3 nodes, the **kindconfigmap.yaml**

``

```
### start of the kindservicetypeloadbalancer.yaml
### for ensuring a unique name: loadbalancer name nginxloady

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginxloady
  annotations:
    metallb.universe.tf/address-pool: production-public-ips
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
```

``

below, the second .yaml file to be added to the Cluster:

```
    # start of the kindconfigmap.yaml
    ## info: the "production-public-ips" can be found 
    ## within the annotations-sector of the kind: Service type: loadbalancer / the kindservicetypeloadbalancer.yaml 
    ## as well... ...namespace: metallb-system & protocol: layer2 
    ## note: as you can see, I added a /32 after every of my node-IPs

 
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: production-public-ips
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 123.223.149.27/32
      - 22.36.211.68/32
      - 192.77.11.164/32
```

``

- add the LoadBalancer:

  `kubectl apply -f kindservicetypeloadbalancer.yaml`
- add the ConfigMap:

  `kubectl apply -f kindconfigmap.yaml`
- Check the status of the namespace ( "n" ) metallb-system:

  `kubectl describe pods -n metallb-system`

PS:
actually it is all there:
https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/

and here:
https://metallb.universe.tf/usage/#requesting-specific-ips

Comment: If I have a public IP or IP ranges, should they be added to the network interface of the master node?